# C# overloading with generics: bug or feature?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0, constraints, overloading

Let's have a following simplified example:

```
void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, params T[] items) 
{
    // ...
}

void Foo<C, T>(C collection, T item)
    where C : ICollection<T>
{
    // ...
}

void Main()
{
    Foo((IEnumerable<int>)new[] { 1 }, 2);
}
```

Compiler says:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' cannot be used as type parameter 'C' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.Foo(C, T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'.

If I change `Main` to:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo<int>((IEnumerable<int>)new[] { 1 }, 2);
}
```

It will work ok. Why compiler does not choose the *right* overload?

Comment: there really is NO conversion between IEnumerable and ICollection.

Comment: @Yossarian: two things. First, there is an explicit conversion. You mean to say "there really is no implicit reference conversion". Second, the question is not "why am I getting a 'no implicit conversion' error?" Second, the question is "why is the overload resolution algorithm picking an exact-match candidate that is invalid instead of picking the valid-but-worse candidate that does not match exactly?"

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the compiler chooses the best match before it uses the generic constraint. In your example the method with the constraint is preferable because it doesn't have a `params` last parameter.

**Edit** - Eric Lippert confirms this in his answer.