# Overloading generic interface parameters in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, parameters

I have created the following class:

```
class GenericTest
{
    public T Do<T>( T test ) where T : class
    {
        return test;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Do<T>( List<T> test ) where T : class
    {
        return test;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Do<T>( IEnumerable<T> test ) where T : class
    {
        return test;
    }

}
```

This has three overloads of the Do() function.  I'm trying to understand how the method parameter matching works in C# for generics, especially around interface parameters.  So, I have the following test program:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    GenericTest testing = new GenericTest();

    string s = "TEST";

    List<string> list = new List<string> {s};

    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
    stack.Push( s );

    testing.Do( s );  //calls public T Do<T>( T test ) 
    testing.Do( list ); //calls IEnumerable<T> Do<T>( List<T> test )
    testing.Do( stack ); //calls public T Do<T>( T test ) where T : class

}
```

The first call to Do() works as I expected, then the concrete class List parameter matches nicely against the List parameter method, but when I pass an IEnumerable, the compiler doesn't use the IEnumerable parameter method, instead it chooses the generic T method.  Is this expected behaviour?  Can I not overload with just an interface parameter in a generic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# overloading with generics: bug or feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586666/c-sharp-overloading-with-generics-bug-or-feature)

Comment: Eric lippert has a great post explaining your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: It is a close duplicate but this question is a lot clearer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So close that question as a duplicate of this one. Its accepted answer is a link-only answer so it's no use anyway

Comment: But then this one would get the same link-only answer, at best.

Comment: The link suggests that a compiler error will occur, but this is not the behaviour I am seeing.  I'm wondering why the matching algorithm picks T over IEnumerable<T> in the parameters when the parameter implements IEnumerable?  Having read the link, I'm still not sure I'm clear on this.

Comment: The compiler error depends on how you set it up. You are just seeing the 'wrong' method being selected. But not wrong according to the language specs.

Comment: So, just to clarify there's no way of having `public IEnumerable<T> Do<T>( IEnumerable<T> test )` ever match when you have a `public T Do<T>( T test )` member as well?

Comment: To sum it up: don't overdo overloading. Your sample needs refactoring of the method-names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if first call works as expected since `string` is `IEnumerable<char>` ...
Which method should be executed in such case? It depends on your particular requirement.

Behaviour that you are describing may be flexibly implemented following [CoR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern where you define matching logic and chain elements order according your particular needs.

Below is just an illustration that shows the idea(I'm sure it can be refactored):

```
public abstract class ChainElem
{
    public abstract bool IsMatching(object o);
    public abstract void Do(object o);
}

public class ChainElemIList : ChainElem{
    public override bool IsMatching(object o) {
        //Matches IList implementations only.
        if( o is IList )
            return true; 
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override void Do(object o) {
        //Do something with the IList
        Console.WriteLine("processing IList...");
    }
}

public class ChainElemIEnumerable : ChainElem{
    public override bool IsMatching(object o) {
        //Matches all IEnumerable implementations(but not string).
        //This is something that you won't achieve with generics.
        if( o is IEnumerable && !(o is string) )
            return true; 
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override void Do(object o) {
        //Do something with the IEnumerable(but not string)
        Console.WriteLine("processing IEnumerable(but not string)...");
    }
}

public class ChainElemString : ChainElem{
    public override bool IsMatching(object o) {
        //Matches strings only.
        if( o is string )
            return true; 
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override void Do(object o) {
        //Do something with the string
        Console.WriteLine("processing string...");
    }
}

public class ChainElemObject : ChainElem{
    public override bool IsMatching(object o) {
        //Matches everything else.  
        return true; 
    }

    public override void Do(object o) {
        //Do something with the object
        Console.WriteLine("processing object...");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    string s = "TEST";
    List<string> list = new List<string> {s};
    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
    stack.Push( s );
    object o = new object();

    //construct the chain - order is important and depends on your requirements
    var chain = new List<ChainElem> {
        new ChainElemIList(),
        new ChainElemIEnumerable(),
        new ChainElemString(),
        new ChainElemObject()
    };

    //processing
    chain.First(c => c.IsMatching(list)).Do(list);
    chain.First(c => c.IsMatching(stack)).Do(stack);
    chain.First(c => c.IsMatching(s)).Do(s);
    chain.First(c => c.IsMatching(o)).Do(o);

    //OUTPUT:
    //  processing IList...
    //  processing IEnumerable(but not string)...
    //  processing string...
    //  processing object...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The IEnumerable call never gets matched at all.  I did think about using reflection to establish whether a parameter supported IEnumerable, but really I wanted the compiler to pick the correct method.  I think the IEnumerable call may never get matched, but I feel the compiler should be spitting out a warning or error based on two matching method types, rather than picking one.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that you can't overload with a interface parameter if you have generic method that matches the signature.

Either use a different name for your methods, or a concrete class in the parameter list.